# I have a dataframe in which one columns contains day and time and I want to put each day and its time in different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe in which one column contains day and its time, I want to put that each day and its time in its respective column.

I have put a '$' in each day to either split or use it to put it in its respective column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'timings' : 'Friday 10 am - 6:30 pm$Saturday 10am-6:30pm$Sunday Closed$Monday 10am-6:30pm$Tuesday 10am-6:30pm$Wednesday 10am-6:30pm$Thursday 10am-6:30pm',
'monday':'','tuesday':'','wednesday':'','thursday':'','friday':'','saturday':'','sunday':''
}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

For e.g.:
Data contains df['timing'] = "friday 10 am, saturday 6:30pm", then in df['friday'] = '10 am' and df['saturday'] = '6:30pm'.

I dont know how to put it in words.

Please me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract the day name and times and then reshaping the DataFrame:

```
(df['timings'].str.extractall(r'(?P<day>[^$\s]+)\s+([^$]+)')
 .droplevel('match')
 .set_index('day', append=True)[1].unstack('day')
)
```

Output:

```
day           Friday       Monday     Saturday  Sunday     Thursday      Tuesday    Wednesday
0    10 am - 6:30 pm  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm  Closed  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm
```

If you want to keep the original order of the days:

```
(df['timings'].str.extractall('(?P<day>[^$\s]+)\s+([^$]+)')
 .set_index('day', append=True)[1].unstack(['match', 'day'])
 .droplevel('match', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
day           Friday     Saturday  Sunday       Monday      Tuesday    Wednesday     Thursday
0    10 am - 6:30 pm  10am-6:30pm  Closed  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm
```

Alternative to sort based on a custom order (here Friday first):

```
from calendar import day_name

sorter = pd.Series({d: (i+3)%7 for i,d in enumerate(day_name)})

out = (df['timings']
 .str.extractall('(?P<day>[^$\s]+)\s+([^$]+)')
 .droplevel('match')
 .set_index('day', append=True)[1].unstack('day')
 .sort_index(axis=1, key=sorter.get)
)
```

##### joining duplicates as string:

```
from calendar import day_name

sorter = pd.Series({d: (i+3)%7 for i,d in enumerate(day_name)})

out = (df['timings']
 .str.extractall('(?P<day>[^$\s]+)\s+([^$]+)')
 .droplevel('match')
 .set_index('day', append=True)[1]
 .groupby(level=[0,1]).agg('/'.join)
 .unstack('day')
 .sort_index(axis=1, key=sorter.get)
)
```

Output:

```
day           Friday     Saturday  Sunday                   Monday      Tuesday    Wednesday     Thursday
0    10 am - 6:30 pm  10am-6:30pm  Closed  10am-12pm/1:30pm-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm
```

Comment: thanks it works, but what if 'monday' is repeated twice then it is giving me error....

Comment: What should happen in this case? Keep the first/last? merge?

Comment: it should merge

Comment: please provide an additional example with the matching expected output for clarity

Comment: @Rushabh I added an example if you want to concatenate the strings

Answer (score 0):

Use nested list comprehension for list of dictionaries, then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [dict(y.split(maxsplit=1) for y in x.split('$')) for x in df['timings']]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index)
print (df)  
            Friday     Saturday  Sunday       Monday      Tuesday  \
0  10 am - 6:30 pm  10am-6:30pm  Closed  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm   

     Wednesday     Thursday  
0  10am-6:30pm  10am-6:30pm
```

EDIT: If need `merge` duplicated days use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = []
for x in df['timings']:

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for y in x.split('$'):
        k, v = y.split(maxsplit=1)
        d[k].append(v)
    out.append({k: '/'.join(v) for k, v in d.items()})

df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index)
```

Comment: this also works, but if 'monday' is repeated twice then it is replace the 1st value with 2nd value.

Comment: @RushabhNalawade - answer was edited, joined separator is `/` for duplicated days.